# What is the correct return type for C function which returns different data types

Tags: c

I was once asked to write a function which will return a pointer to some data in the memory upon some successful condition else it should return "-1". In this case, what would be the correct return type. If I only had to return the data then I would have char * as the return type of the function myfunction. But in this case, I may return -1 has return type.

```
<what-type> myfunction() {

char *data;

if (some condition true)
  return data;
else 
  return -1
}

int main () {

 myfunction

}
```

Comment: Couldn't you return `NULL`?

Comment: You can't really officially do that, though there are a few ways to kluge it.

Comment: Or maybe `int myfunction(char** data_out);` where a return value of zero means `*data_out` has been assigned.

Comment: I think the correct answer would have been "no."

Comment: @Heath: How can the correct answer be "no" when the question asked is "what?"

Comment: return `uintptr_t`, then check return value.If it is (uintptr_t)(-1) means error, otherwise means success

Comment: A common alternative pattern is to have a function accept a pointer to a pointer so that it can fill in a pointer as a result, and have the success/error code as its return value.

Comment: @Alok - Regardless of whether one can "figure out" a way to return either a pointer or -1, if the questioner means to do so through the return value, I believe the correct answer is to refuse.  Returning heterogeneous and incompatible types as suggested is such a bad idea (i.e., invokes UB) that the question should not be answered as if it were a reasonable question.  It is not and it should be treated as a nonsense question.  You used NULL, rather than -1, in your answer because you realize the suggested behavior from the question is unacceptable.

Comment: @Heath: True all of it but then the answer is to suggest the correct way of doing it, my only objection was to "no" as answer not the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @Alok:  The question asked is not "how do I?" but "what return type?"  The correct answer is probably, "none" or "you can't do that as you described."  I didn't mean to say one should stop with a one-word answer, especially on stackoverflow, just that one should clearly decline to do precisely that which was asked.  Thus, "no."

Answer (score 7):

Use `union` and perhaps define a `typedef` for it.

i.e.

```
typedef struct {
   int is_error;
   union {
     int error_code;
     char *data;
   }
} ReturnType;
```

Then

```
ReturnType myFunction(....) { ... etc }
```

The caller can check if the function is error (get a return error code) or get the `data` otherwise.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - One assumes that the caller plays the game and check `is_error` first to decide what value of `error_code` or `data` is the one to choose.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I do not think that you understand how `union` works. The `typedef` says that we have a bit of memory that can be viewed as either a `char *` or and `int`. (using the same amount of memory. To determine how to use that part (interpret) of memory depends on the value of `is_error`. If `is_error` is true then interpret the rest as the `error_code`. Otherwise use that pert of the memory as a `char *`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724617/examples-of-union-in-c - Oh it is platform independent - part of the C programming language.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - You can say that about any type. Lets say an integer. Why not interpret it as a pointer. But one assumes that the programmer uses the type as an indicator and its semantics to say it is a number, not a pointer. But the typedef given helps both the compiler and the programmer to understand the semantics. Where does the platform bit come in? Surely an idiot for a programmer that cannot understand the code given could do all sort of things.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - the `int` called `is_error` indicated how to treat the `union`. i.e. `error_code` or otherwise `data`.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - It does not need to have any guarantees. As the `is_error` bit of the structure has told the programmer to use `error_code` (not a pointer) or `data` (a pointer)

Comment: The problem here is that your words don't match your code.  You say "use union" but you really mean "use a struct with another field to qualify the union".  And you say "check if the function is error" but in your code is error is a struct field, not a function or macro.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Lets be pedantic. But the trust of the question is to return two different types. In C it requires the struct bit to determine what type of the union to employ.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to return different data types, Use a `void*`:

```
void* myfunction();
^^^^^
```

In your case returning a `NULL` seems to be the more ideal solution rather than the `-1`.
It will allow users of your function to write code such as:

```
if(myfunction())
{
    //Utilize the returned string
}
```

Comment: Please do not use `void` - It is a leap into the err.. umm. `void`.

Comment: @EdHeal: `void *` has its own uses in C. No language features are bad(*barring very rare exceptions*). It's horses for courses. In this case `NULL` is the more appropriate solution though it doesn't discredit the use of `void *` as a generic type in C.

Comment: I just think that using `void` is given in the towel. All bets are off with type checking. As to your assumption `no language features are bad` see Javascript and the notion that it is an object oriented language for full details (or English (i before e except after c), French (masculine and feminine verbs), ...

Comment: @EdHeal: *All bets are off with type checking*. And sometimes it is very much desirable even with the risks involved. Ofcourse, when I said *language* I was referring to C the language governed by the ISO standard. As for the rest of languages I cannot say for sure because they do not have governing standards or committee's.

Comment: Is it not better to get the compiler (before you get to run time environment) to do as much checking as possible? Saves time. Saves money. Saves effort. Perhaps using as much of the compilers ability to check things left you off earlier on Fridays?!

Answer (score 0):

> function which will return a pointer .. upon some successful condition else it should return "-1".

Do yourself a favour and do **not** mix error indication and function result into one object like that. Split them out in two distinct entities by letting the function just return a boolean success indicator, and return the actual result data though a pointer like

```
bool myfunction(char **result_ptr) {
        char *data;

        if (some error condition)
                return false;

        *result_ptr = data;
        return true;
}

int main () {
        bool success;
        char *data:

        success = myfunction(&data);
        if (success)
                use(data);

}
```

In-band error indicators makes poor APIs that often invite failures (in the extreme case of the `realloc` function, it begs you to write code that looses the original pointer in case of failure), and it fails at least the following [Characteristics of a Good API](http://research.google.com/pubs/archive/32713.pdf)

- Easy to use, even without documentation
- Hard to misuse
- Easy to read and maintain code that uses it

[CERT recommend against them](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/ERR02-C.+Avoid+in-band+error+indicators) from a security perspective.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to cast -1 to void * and check for it.
you can return ((void *)-1);  Note that there is no notion of signed-ness of pointers in C.

If you think that it feels a bit crazy :-) you're probably right. But there are instances where this convention may be useful for error handling.   And there are uses of it out there in important projects. In particular implementations of pthread library use this convention at times.

[Can a pointer (address) ever be negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304795/can-a-pointer-address-ever-be-negative)

Has a great deal to say about it.

### On the notion of special interpretations of pointers by their value.

Okay so there seems to be some issue about how guarantees that (void*)-1 is NOT an actual pointer.  and @ictoofay seems to think that somehow I mentioned a guarantee about (void *)-1 above and how it cannot be a valid address, which I would like to clarify that I didn't.

Having said that, assuming that a system that uses direct memory mapping and not virtual addresses.  (void *)-1 would be the very last address in that model, and in the strictest sense you shouldn't use it.  However, you can make assumptions about the storage capacity of the last physical address (see ldl example below)

But the notion of "special" interpretation to of pointers by examining there value in real life projects is not new. Actually, it is a notion USED in most modern operating systems when they do memory address management.  It is quite common that a system will use  addresses and address ranges and use them for "special meaning". So in reality, you as a programmer ARE actually free to make whatever assumptions and live with their consequences. The notion that (void *)-1 can be used as a special value is not far fetched. Note that this still does NOT say anything about the (in?)compatibility  of the notion with the fact that (void *)-1 could be a valid address in a given case.

Now for addressing this "crazy" notion and why would any one use. Here are two real life examples of where (void*)-1 is being safely.

pthreads uses it on Linux, HPUX, solaris and most BSDs.

In particular PTHREAD_CANCELED is a ((void *)-1)

From pthread.h

`#define PTHREAD_CANCELED ((void *) -1)`

It's defined as ((void *)1) in the darwin version of the pthread libraries. Fun fun;

In glibc (with _GNU_SOURCE defined), ld.so provides the ability to search for alternate value of the same symbol in dynamically loaded libraries. There the value for  RTLD_NEXT is (void *)-1.

### A thought on fluidity of C

In C is no reason why a given value has to be interpreted in a particular way.  C is not strictly typed and is fluid in these notions. A LOT of its power comes from that.

### On 'value' of NULL

[Can a conforming C implementation #define NULL to be something wacky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599207/can-a-conforming-c-implementation-define-null-to-be-something-wacky)

has fun explanation of notions.

Comment: How can you guarantee that `(void *)-1` won't be a valid pointer that points to a genuine result?

Comment: Sure, in specific environments you can guarantee it, but you can't guarantee it *in general*, and the question seemed not to be talking specifically about pthread implementations that use that. Frankly, if you don't care about guarantees, you might as well return the string literal `"failed"` whenever you might otherwise return `-1`; sure, it's *unlikely* that it would ever return that, but wouldn't you prefer a *guarantee*?

Comment: @icktoofay I think that there is a balance between absolute guarantees everywhere about values and how to interpret them; after all NULL which is (void *)0 is also—strictly speaking—a VALID memory address.

Comment: The standard offers guarantees that an object will not have an address of `NULL`. I don't believe it offers that guarantee for any other address. (By the way, `(void *)0` might not even be zero in memory; there is quite a bit of gymnastics to make all `0`s in pointers some other value when `NULL` is not actually memory address `0`.)

Comment: There's a big difference between what the authors of a kernel can do in terms of using special pointer values (they can just decide to reserve any range of the virtual address space for them), and what the authors of portable user-mode programs can do (very little, without depending on unique promises made by a given kernel-hardware combination)

Comment: @ChrisStratton We are not in a disagreement. However throwing in  restrictions like "portability" is not fair :-).  My point is very simple: You, as a C programmer have the luxury of a fluid non-strictly typed language, and therefore you can do whatever you want with whatever values and then live with the consequences of those choices. That's all.

Comment: If one wants a `char` pointer value within an application that is guaranteed to indicate a special condition and to be unequal to any other pointer value, then one can simply declare `extern char SpecialCondition[1];` and define it in one source file. This is perfectly conforming, and no contortions of standard interpretation or special features of a C implementation are needed.

Answer (score -1):

If not using NULL, then you can typecast the return value

```
char* myfuntion(){  
                return (char*)-1;
}
int main () {
 printf("%d",myfuntion());
}
```