# How the char array in union is working?

Tags: c

```
static int i = 2;
union U {
  int a, b;
  char c[3];
}u;


 int main(){
   u.b = 0x6;
   for(;i; u.b++)
    u.b = u.a << i--;
  printf("%d %o %s", u.a, u.b, u.c);
 return 0;
}
```

This code gives the output for the character array as 3. Now I know that this code poses several `Undefined Behaviour` specially when I am a storing into one variable and accessing of some other, but just for the purpose of experiment, can anybody explain to me why `u.c` has a value of `3`.

**Note: Internal memory structure would be better to understand this**

Comment: Use "step" in your debugger and inspect the modifications of the variables.

Comment: Can you please explain it theoretically that how `u.c` has the value of 3..I understand for `u.a` and `u.b`

Comment: I suggest to read about union in C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724617/examples-of-union-in-c

Comment: Do you know what `union` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the for loop the union `u` contains the bits:

```
0x00000033
```

which split into chars are

```
0x33 0x00 0x00
```

so

```
c[0]=0x33
c[1]=0x00
c[2]=0x00
```

and 0x33 happens to be the ASCII code for the digit '3';

Comment: I think OP is asking why the result is 0x33

Comment: Thanks brother...I actually mixed between ASCII code 0x33 and decimal value 3...I was thinking the decimal value to be 33...I definitely need some coffee..

Answer (score 0):

You can symply test it printing the hex code of a with:

```
printf("\n%X\n", u.a);
```

Output will be `0x33`, that is `ASCII 3`

The for loop do

- Start with `b=0x06`
- Then left shift by `2` => `b=0x18`
- Inc b => b= 0x19
- Then left shift `b` by `1` => `b=0x32`
- Inc `b` => `b= 0x33`

You define an union then a coincide with `b`. 
First 3 byte of `a` and `b` are also accessible by `c`.

BTW printf output depends on endianess of data.

In your case, **Little Endian**, `printf` print ASCII 3, because of `c` is:

```
c[0]=0x33
c[1]=0x00
c[2]=0x00
```

In case of **Big Endian** `printf` print nothing, because of `c` is:

```
c[0]=0x00
c[1]=0x00
c[2]=0x00
```

Answer (score 0):

u.a, u.b and c's bytes all occupy the same memory. Since u.a. and u.b have the same type they are essentially the same variable. The loop

```
int i=2;
u.b = 6;
for(;i; u.b++)
    u.b = u.a << i--;
```

can be written (just using u.b for clarity) as:

```
u.b = 6;

u.b = u.b << 2;  // u.b is now 24 (one bit shift left is multiplying by 2)
u.b++;           // u.b is now 25

u.b = u.b << 1; // u.b is now 50
u.b++;          // u.b is now 51.
```

Now the memory layout of a 32 bit integer on a PC with low byte first is, byte wise, 51-00-00-00.

Interpreting these bytes as a string, as you told printf to do with the `%s` conversion,  means that 51 is taken as an ascii value, denoting the letter *3*. Fortunately the next byte is indeed 0, because the integer is small, so that the string is terminated. printf will print *3*.